# Do I really need -dmS option in screen to run background job stably even log out?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I saw many place introduce `screen` to run background job stably even log out. They use

```
screen -dmS name
```

According to `screen -h`, this option means

> -dmS name     Start as daemon: Screen session in detached mode.

What is daemon? I don't understand.

I found that if I simply type `screen`, I can enter automatically into a screen. After I run some command, and press `Ctrl+a d`, and then log off. The job is still running fine. **So is this simple approach OK? Do I really need `-dmS` to make background job stable?**

---

Let me try to give a summary:

Anything run in screen is safe to logging out (but you should detach the screen, not quit screen when you log out), no matter what the option you have set to screen.

`-dmS` is just an option convienient for submitting jobs in background noniteractively. That is

```
screen -dmS nameOfScreen command
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would only use `-dm` if you want to run a command in a screen session and not enter it interactively

`-S` is just to give the session a usable name so you can reconnect to it again easily later

If you want to use it interactively and don't want to give it a human readable name, you can omit all of those arguments safely.

For example, if you just want to start up `screen` to run the command, say, `/path/to/longTime` and you don't want to watch it run you could do it either as

```
screen -dmS longSession /path/to/longTime
```

or you could do

```
screen -S longSession
$ /path/to/longTime
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Both would accomplish the same thing, but one is both easier to script and a bit less typing.

Comment: Hi, Eric Renouf. I don't quite understand "You would only use -dm if you want to run a command in a screen session and not enter it interactively" . `-dm` mean detached, how could I run command without enter it? If I enter the screen, then it is interactive. Am I right?

Comment: @user15964 you can give the command to execute within the screen session on the command line and never interactively be in the screen session.  That's what `-dm` helps do.  So no, you do not have to enter screen interactively, you can give it the command you want to run without typing it within the session directly

Comment: @user15964 see my update to hopefully be a little clearer how the two options compare

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to write a summary, to see if I am wrong somewhere : )

Comment: Hi Eric. How would you clean up the screens later on ? Is there a possibility of closing that hidden screen once the script is done ? Otherwise I am thinking of closing all screens at certain interval. If I give my script to end-user and use your method, every time a screen will be open without me or them knowing, eventually litter each terminal with zombie screens.

Comment: @Kenny when the scripts end the screen sessions should automatically go away with this technique.  If they are lingering, perhaps the program they're running isn't actually done yet, unless your program opens an interactive shell or something like that at the end.  But as is, when `/path/to/longTime` finishes in this example, `screen` will exit as well

Answer (score 4):

It's more useful as `screen -dmS name command args`  - that will start a screen session called `name` in the background (i.e. detached), and run `command args` inside that screen session.

Without the `command args`, it will just start the screen session in the background.

In either case, you can attach to that session later with, e.g., `screen -d -r name`.    From `man screen`:

> `-d|-D [pid.tty.host]`
>
> does  not  start screen, but detaches the elsewhere running screen session. It has the same effect as typing "C-a  d"  from  screen's controlling  terminal.  `-D`  is  the equivalent to the power detach key.  If no session can be detached, this option  is  ignored.  In combination  with  the  `-r` / `-R`  option more powerful effects can be achieved:
>
> `-d -r`   Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.
>
> `-d -R`   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.
>
> `-d -RR`  Reattach  a  session  and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first session if more than one session is available.
>
> `-D -r`   Reattach a session. If necessary  detach  and  logout  remotely first.
>
> `-D -R`   Attach here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary detach  and  logout  remotely first.   If  it  was not running create it and notify the user.  This is the author's favorite.
>
> `-D -RR`  Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it.
>
> Note: It is always a good idea to check the status  of  your  sessions by means of `screen -list`.

That man page is missing an important detail here - it should read:

> `-d|-D [pid.tty.host|session name]`

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed information, very useful : )

Answer (score 2):

-dmS just enforces these things:

1. It will start detached. `-dm`
2. And you can name your session. `-S sessioname`

Running as a daemon indicates that it will execute the specified command in the background until execution finishes.

Starting screen, then running the command, then detaching should have the same behavior as using -dmS to run the command. I often run game servers or long jobs by starting screen, then detaching with `Ctrl-A+d`

You can also check the man pages `man screen` for more in depth info on the options.