# Python open screen and execute inside screen

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, python, gnu-screen

I have a py script S1 that I would need to execute inside a screen. On an end-user point of view, I would like them to just execute another python script S2, which will open a screen and execute the script S1 inside that screen.

My `S2.py` is like this :

```
import os 
os.cmd('echo Outside main terminal')
os.cmd('screen -S sTest')
os.cmd('echo I would like to be inside screen here. Not successfully!. How to send command to screen instead of remaining at main Terminal')
os.cmd('spark-submit S1.py') #this should execute inside screen. currently main Terminal is the one that runs it
#Additional steps to check status, clean up, check if screen is active then spawn another sTest2 sTest3, otherwise close and/or reuse screen sTest, etc.
screen_list = os.cmd('screen -ls')
if 'sTest' in screen_list ...... #let python process
```

What I want is that end-users can simply run `python S2.py`, the screen hassle is handled by me at the back. I will need to have extra mechanism to clean up screen, use existing screens etc. Giving users instruction to open screen themselves will litter every terminal with screens.

The reason `S1.py` needs to be inside screen is due to SSH connection stability if run on main Terminal.

Comment: Consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280025/do-i-really-need-dms-option-in-screen-to-run-background-job-stably-even-log-out/280026#280026 (and also look at the `subprocess` module for doing command actions)

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to use subprocess and write the command to screen's stdin.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('screen -S sTest', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('echo I would like to be inside screen here.\n')
proc.stdin.write('spark-submit S1.py\n')
statusProc = subprocess.run('screen -ls', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
statusString = statusProc.stdout.decode('ascii')
# parse screen's output (statusString) for your status list
```

You'll probably want to brush up on subprocess.Popen's documentation because there are probably specifics about how to close subprocesses like that properly, but this should get you on the right track.